# How not to miss the next element after itertools.takewhile()

Tags: python, python-itertools

Say we wish to process an iterator and want to handle it by chunks.
The logic per chunk depends on previously-calculated chunks, so `groupby()` does not help.

Our friend in this case is itertools.takewhile():

```
while True:
    chunk = itertools.takewhile(getNewChunkLogic(), myIterator)
    process(chunk)
```

The problem is that `takewhile()` needs to go past the last element that meets the new chunk logic, thus 'eating' the first element for the next chunk.

There are various solutions to that, including wrapping or à la C's `ungetc()`, etc..
My question is: is there an **elegant** solution?

Comment: get cython out and create your own

Answer (score 11):

`takewhile()` indeed needs to look at the next element to determine when to toggle behaviour.

You could use a wrapper that tracks the last seen element, and that can be 'reset' to back up one element:

```
_sentinel = object()

class OneStepBuffered(object):
    def __init__(self, it):
        self._it = iter(it)
        self._last = _sentinel
        self._next = _sentinel
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self._next is not _sentinel:
            next_val, self._next = self._next, _sentinel
            return next_val
        try:
            self._last = next(self._it)
            return self._last
        except StopIteration:
            self._last = self._next = _sentinel
            raise
    next = __next__  # Python 2 compatibility
    def step_back(self):
        if self._last is _sentinel:
            raise ValueError("Can't back up a step")
        self._next, self._last = self._last, _sentinel
```

Wrap your iterator in this one before using it with `takewhile()`:

```
myIterator = OneStepBuffered(myIterator)
while True:
    chunk = itertools.takewhile(getNewChunkLogic(), myIterator)
    process(chunk)
    myIterator.step_back()
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> test_list = range(10)
>>> iterator = OneStepBuffered(test_list)
>>> list(takewhile(lambda i: i < 5, iterator))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> iterator.step_back()
>>> list(iterator)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: It depends on how your original iterator was coded if performance is killed. If everything else was coded in C, then yes, this adds a step back into the Python interpreter and that can affect performance. The alternative is to re-tool your algorithm to not rely on `takewhile()`. Without details as to what you are doing that's not something I can help with at this point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, that's what I meant. I'm not doing anything, the OP is someone else ;) As for the `ValueError`: it makes perfect sense from your `OneStepBuffered`'s viewpoint, but for OP's task, that's looks like a bug to me.

Comment: well, assuming that it's a valid scenario.... note: you can catch the exception if that's the case

Comment: assume an endless, but fast, iterator.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. You might wish to use `itertools.tee` or `itertools.pairwise` (new in Python 3.10) to deal with this, but I didn't think those solutions were very elegant.

The best I found is to just rewrite takewhile. Based heavily on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
def takewhile_inclusive(predicate, it):
  for x in it:
    if predicate(x):
      yield x
    else:
      yield x
      break
```

In your loop you can elegantly treat the final element separately using unpacking:

```
*chunk,lastPiece = takewhile_inclusive(getNewChunkLogic(), myIterator)
```

You can then chain the last piece:

```
lastPiece = None
while True:
  *chunk,lastPiece = takewhile_inclusive(getNewChunkLogic(), myIterator)
  if lastPiece is not None:
    myIterator = itertools.chain([lastPiece], myIterator))
```

Comment: You could shorten that to `for x in it:` `yield x` `if not predicate(x):` `break`.

Comment: If the input iterator is "empty", your `*chunk,lastPiece = ...` crashes.

Comment: Your initial `lastPiece = None` is pointless, that value is never used. And I can't make sense of your `if lastPiece is not None`. Why are you removing `None` values from the input iterator? And why only if they're right after a chunk?

Comment: Nested chains can become slow, as all elements get moved through the whole stack of chain iterators.

Comment: @KellyBund the problem OP had was takewhile "'eating' the first element for the next chunk". So the `if lastPiece is not None` part of the code is pushing the last piece back in the front of the iterator, so it isn't 'eaten'. I like your suggestion to shorten it, I just wrote it in this verbose way to mirror the linked documentation.

Comment: But why are you looking for `None`? Why not `if lastPiece != 42`? What makes `None` special here?

Answer (score 0):

Given the callable `GetNewChunkLogic()` will report `True` along first chunk and `False` afterward.
The following snippet

1. solves the 'additional next step' problem of `takewhile` .
2. is elegant because you don't have to implement the back-one-step logic .

---

```
def partition(pred, iterable):
    'Use a predicate to partition entries into true entries and false entries'
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) -->  1 3 5 7 9 and 0 2 4 6 8
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filter(pred, t1), filterfalse(pred, t2)

while True:
    head, tail = partition(GetNewChunkLogic(), myIterator)
    process(head)
    myIterator = tail
```

However, the most elegant way is to modify your `GetNewChunkLogic` into a generator and remove the `while` loop.

Comment: This is very bad. Even if the current chunk logic does keep reporting only `False` afterwards, never `True` again (which isn't guaranteed), this is very problematic. Every `head` always runs all the way to the end of the `myIterator`, which is slow and loads it all into memory. And filtering values through the whole stack of `filterfalse` iterators that you build is slow, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you can do it. Yield a value (`sentinel`) when the predicate fails, but *before* yielding the value itself. Then group by values which aren't the `sentinel`.

Here, `group_by_predicate` requires a function that returns a predicate (`pred_gen`).  This is recreated every time the predicate fails:

```
from itertools import groupby


def group_by_predicate(predicate_gen, _iter):
    sentinel = object()
    def _group_with_sentinel():
        pred = predicate_gen()
        for n in _iter:
            while not pred(n):
                yield sentinel
                pred = predicate_gen()
            yield n
            
    g = _group_with_sentinel()
    for k, g in groupby(g, lambda s: s!=sentinel):
        if k:
            yield g
```

This can then be used like:

```
def less_than_gen(maxn):
    """Return a predicate that returns true while the sum of inputs is < maxn"""
    def pred(i):
        pred.count += i
        return pred.count < maxn
    pred.count = 0
    return pred

data = iter(list(range(9)) * 3)

for g in group_by_predicate(lambda: less_than_gen(15), data):
    print(list(g))
```

Which outputs groups of numbers whose sum is all less than 15:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7]
[8, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6, 7]
[8, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6, 7]
[8]
```