# printing characters before and after takewhile in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, while-loop, python-itertools

I have a python list in which i need to do takewhile. I am getting output as

`['fd', 'dfdf', 'keyword', 'ssd', 'sdsd']` but I need to get `['3=', 'fd', 'dfdf', 'keyword', 'ssd', 'sdsd', ';']`

```
 from itertools import takewhile, chain

l = [1, 2, "3=", "fd", "dfdf", "keyword", "ssd", "sdsd", ";", "dds"]

s = "keyword"

# get all elements on the right of s
right = takewhile(lambda x: ';' not in x, l[l.index(s) + 1:])

# get all elements on the left of s using a reversed sublist
left = takewhile(lambda x: '=' not in x, l[l.index(s)::-1])

# reverse the left list back and join it to the right list
subl = list(chain(list(left)[::-1], right))

print(subl)
# ['fd', 'dfdf', 'keyword', 'ssd', 'sdsd']
```

Comment: Are you required to use `takewhile`?

Comment: What do you want do u want to eradicate integers in the list?

Answer (score 1):

the problem with [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=takewhile#itertools.takewhile) is to get the element that satisfies the condition.

you could try this (if i understood your question correctly)

```
l = [1, 2, "3=",  "fd", "dfdf", "keyword", "ssd", "sdsd", ";", "dds"]

it = iter(l)

first_index = next(i for i, item in enumerate(it) 
                   if isinstance(item, str) and '=' in item)
last_index = next(i for i, item in enumerate(it, start=first_index+1) 
                  if isinstance(item, str) and ';' in item)

print(l[first_index:last_index + 1])
```

this creates an iterator `it` (so that the `item`s that have been checked against the fist condition will not be checked again).

the rest should be pretty straightforward.

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615659/how-not-to-miss-the-next-element-after-itertools-takewhile) might also be helpful.