# Sequential chaining of itertools operators

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I'm looking for a nice way to sequentially combine two itertools operators. As an example, suppose we want to select numbers from a generator sequence greater than a threshold, after having gotten past that threshold. For a threshold of 12000, these would correspond to `it.takewhile(lambda x: x<12000)` and `it.takewhile(lambda x: x>=12000)`:

```
# Set up an example generator:
def lcg(a=75,c=74,m=2**16+1,x0 = 1):
    xn = x0
    yield xn
    while True:
        xn = (a*xn+c) % m
        yield xn
```

```
# First 20 elements:

list(it.islice(lcg(), 20))

[1,      # <- start sequence, start it.takewhile(lambda x: x<12000)
 149,
 11249,  # <- last element of it.takewhile(lambda x: x<12000)
 57305,  # <- start it.takewhile(lambda x: x>=12000) here
 38044,
 35283,
 24819,
 26463,
 18689,
 25472,  # <- last element of it.takewhile(lambda x: x>=12000); end of sequence
 9901,
 21742,
 57836,
 12332,
 7456,
 34978,
 1944,
 14800,
 61482,
 23634]
```

Is there a way to select the sequence of greater than 12000, including the initial values less than 12000, i.e. the desired output is:

```
[1, 149, 11249, 57305, 38044, 35283, 24819, 26463, 18689, 25472]
```

This is trivial to do with two for-loops, but I'm looking for an itertools-type way (maybe a one-liner?) of combining the two operators without reseting the `lcg` generator.

Comment: See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615659/how-not-to-miss-the-next-element-after-itertools-takewhile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to writing a one-liner for the problem with the existing `itertools` library would be to use a flag variable with `{0}` as a default value to indicate which predicate to use. At first the flag evaluates to a truthy value so that the first predicate (`x < 12000`) is made effective, and if the first predicate fails, pop the set so the flag becomes falsey to make the second predicate (`x >= 12000`) effective. By popping `0` from the set, it also allows the expression to fall back to the second predicate on the same iteration when the first predicate fails:

```
takewhile(lambda x, f={0}: f and (x < 12000 or f.pop()) or x >= 12000, lcg())
```

Note that it's safe to use a mutable object as the default value of an argument in this case because `lambda` creates a new function object along with a new instance of the mutable object every time it's evaluated.

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/VirtualGuiltyRatio

Comment: Innovative approach! I assume `f.add(1)` (`f.clear()` in the edited version) does not evaluate as True and so, logically, if we get to that predicate, the final condition is evaluated as well.

Comment: Yes that's correct. `f.clear()` always returns `None`, a falsey value that makes the `or` operator evaluate the next operand. I've updated my answer by flipping the truthiness of the default argument so that a few characters are saved.

Answer (score 1):

Like [blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75954983/1672429), I use a *single* `takewhile` with a *stateful* predicate. But I use a generator, so Python keeps track of the state for me, as progress in my code. That's faster, at least for longer cases.

```
def pred():
    x = yield
    while x < 12000:
        x = yield True
    while x >= 12000:
        x = yield True
    yield False
pred = pred()
next(pred)
result = takewhile(pred.send, lcg())

print(*result)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZFBTsMwEEXF1qf4m0p2GlBSAUUVZskJuECUTKiFY0eOI9KzsOkGDsVpcGwSlR1ezfi_-TOa-fjqT_5ozfn8Ofr2-uH7yrfOdlCenLdWD1Bdb52Hr97o_ag0MdZQC12_8kru73LUcn-bo5M7ZBnKe2xR5pgKWYoDQ3iTgQx5jE-KdBN-YhLd8OJGSuAK8wrZHG1RC2zQrepaHkfoHTV8aRLKonrhPOER5a4oigv7BYtt_7BP8h9wSp8rPRCb2wciTcEMTZ7PsWCOhlH7IK0ri8LNQKbJ4-KEYKFcGc-zBIu0_N8bLLf4AQ)):

```
1 149 11249 57305 38044 35283 24819 26463 18689 25472
```

Easy to extend if you want more than two phases, just add more loops.

Benchmark results for your small example:

```
lcg()
  2.63 ± 0.01 μs  Stefan_selfmade
  3.33 ± 0.02 μs  Stefan_nonlocal
  3.39 ± 0.02 μs  Stefan_generator
  3.53 ± 0.03 μs  blhsing
  3.83 ± 0.03 μs  blhsing_old
```

`Stefan_generator` is my above solution, `blhsing` is their current solution. The others are included for curiosity (`Stefan_nonlocal` instead uses a `bool` flag, I wanted to see how that compares to blhsing's `set` flag. `Stefan_selfmade` is without `takewhile`, fast but not very nice. `blhsing_old` is an older version with multiple `clear()`).

Much of the time is spent in your `lcg` generator, so I also tried running the solutions on a precomputed list of its results, to better compare the time spent in our solutions:

```
list(islice(lcg(), 20))
  1.13 ± 0.01 μs  Stefan_selfmade
  1.66 ± 0.02 μs  Stefan_nonlocal
  1.76 ± 0.01 μs  blhsing
  1.78 ± 0.02 μs  Stefan_generator
  2.12 ± 0.01 μs  blhsing_old
```

And I tried longer cases, where my generator's slightly higher setup costs pay off by having faster usage. With 100 to 10000 elements in each of the two phases:

```
100 and 100
 12.06 ± 0.07 μs  Stefan_selfmade
 14.11 ± 0.13 μs  Stefan_generator
 18.83 ± 0.12 μs  Stefan_nonlocal
 19.93 ± 0.21 μs  blhsing
 24.82 ± 0.31 μs  blhsing_old

1000 and 1000
112.88 ± 0.41 μs  Stefan_selfmade
129.49 ± 0.55 μs  Stefan_generator
179.32 ± 2.37 μs  Stefan_nonlocal
192.87 ± 3.03 μs  blhsing
239.37 ± 4.70 μs  blhsing_old

10000 and 10000
  1.11 ± 0.01 ms  Stefan_selfmade
  1.27 ± 0.01 ms  Stefan_generator
  1.79 ± 0.01 ms  Stefan_nonlocal
  1.89 ± 0.02 ms  blhsing
  2.36 ± 0.01 ms  blhsing_old
```

Full code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVbNbtw2EL7rKQYwipUcZSs5sWMvql4K9NRbclssBK5ErQlTlCpyExkLP0kvuST33nvqAzT3PE2HP_pdy0B0kTj85u-b4VB_fa0f1X0lPn_-clTF69vv3reiqUpQrKRMASvrqlFu5fU7Y7mVSkUUk4plstsrKREhynP60UKyinOaKVaJHpPTP4_OAFO0UVXF-z1FHuine8ZpCExyluG7bqr8mCnPy2kB7xUtiEgPVNCGqKrxtQWy5zTYeICPxtQNzX231k8LCTwyyvNeYjyg_BeIr6IoGqATOHxoMM65zq_JDyhZ0e-ESyvToSHSRmgkgrbK12u7bKg6NmKgwWytJRV5CH2qEypEJXiVET5nomCNVOirj6enph1x02lbeC9mhRVMk0TpAmej0Cf5jwMZWBihBz6X01_KXFJelCSn88yZ9qZlw4ZlpGrQHxO4txlnupCTrV3byyg32OfrPwcv-pv4fd7WSzZtIJI-r2Hp85aBDmBY3PN7ycRhzt5ZCTgp9zmBNoQiOUVPGyiAiBz8njbAPIt1XdV-EIDJucvrrHLOZ1rx_Mf8xr3fmduMU9L4L_n1iqPAAZWczY5wfoTCeWeFXcDhOHKbCs8OPkneXYeQJe_ehlAmV3B5CfENvII4hDZKYpdZK9B5axvc1dTWyI4UfWBGw0qDfQKX-usVZAH8BOVsnqC6d3FxAb9VTYOzVVApbUzZPc0e5sTStkYQWuU4qn1DxjbaDajhcBS6WQ1gMzqn8sgH7bmafoiUOMV7ZOI8htCDw15kQVjSdZoKUtI0xQpp3wQpRip1BG7g-w0RB-pfB1qrpkQlb1xGNs1tHN_d3e2QKYJEbU3h9WpvVt1eFngOfmMao-AVUf5KELFCw1q2exER31qIIfx9Takrv6JIh2LK3FR9muJY7ik21lEwTFJiT3VVqBsmlJv59tsoW4GKkGB9rSLACvBbt-yp2MB2NyvOUz_O9f0r_WI0z5XW2ipM3Dg3mkprSrxdcfYbw9tiF2w3cbTbzcdxsTrpG9xXMtjcrK-KJ_j3bziZ69zI3hrZSaf3BKu-cVLtwZYrjqJROEtdZUJ1OTPljvrG_hmMmyyEKOhYTewrgJ-dYGrNJbYmdY23pa9mbe3yN3GE8EAfE0PeKFZblY7SaYuOq6arBK-xZlirjGPzwx_ZwZpJUx15murjkh1QH2vA09TzTLes9MgIVqHG--jg6lq32-q_fyTKYnoTdDB90uzfj88dNAq04sJOCNfR3NS8LDpRax4rZAYpvhFsml4fFC3WB-d2ujbbxsFzocbRYGxu7czc1N6SucHemcFzixOTaLG0Bt8E9r_W_d52v7n_Aw)):

```py
from timeit import timeit
from time import time
from statistics import mean, stdev
from collections import deque
from itertools import takewhile, islice, product

def Stefan_generator(iterable):
    def pred():
        x = yield
        while x < 12000:
            x = yield True
        while x >= 12000:
            x = yield True
        yield False
    pred = pred()
    next(pred)
    return takewhile(pred.send, iterable)

def Stefan_nonlocal(iterable):
    first = True
    def pred(x):
        nonlocal first
        if first:
            if x < 12000:
                return True
            first = False
        return x >= 12000
    return takewhile(pred, iterable)

def Stefan_selfmade(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for x in it:
        if x < 12000:
            yield x
        elif x >= 12000:
            yield x
            for x in it:
                if x >= 12000:
                    yield x
                else:
                    return
        else:
            return

def blhsing(iterable):
    return takewhile(lambda x, f={0}: f and (x < 12000 or f.pop()) or x >= 12000, iterable)

def blhsing_old(iterable):
    return takewhile(lambda x, f={1}: f and x < 12000 or f.clear() or x >= 12000, iterable)


funcs = Stefan_generator, Stefan_nonlocal, Stefan_selfmade, blhsing, blhsing_old

def lcg(a=75, c=74, m=2 ** 16 + 1, x0=1):
    xn = x0
    yield xn
    while True:
        xn = (a * xn + c) % m
        yield xn

### Correctness

def check(iterable):
    expect = list(funcs[0](iterable))
    for f in funcs:
        result = list(f(iterable))
        assert result == expect, (iterable, expect, result, f.__name__)

for a, b, c in product(range(5), repeat=3):
    check([11999] * a + [12000] * b + [11999] * c)
check([6000, float('nan'), 6000])
check([6000, float('nan'), 18000])

### Speed

def test(title, iterable, number, unit, scale):
    print()
    print(title)
    t0 = time()

    times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
    def stats(f):
        ts = [t * scale for t in sorted(times[f])[:10]]
        return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} {unit} '
    for _ in range(100):
        for f in funcs:
            t = timeit(lambda: deque(f(iterable), 0), number=number) / number
            times[f].append(t)
    for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
        print(stats(f), f.__name__)
    print(time() - t0)

class Lcg:
    __iter__ = lcg.__call__

test('lcg()', Lcg(), 2500, 'μs', 1e6)
test('list(islice(lcg(), 20))', list(islice(lcg(), 20)), 5000, 'μs', 1e6)
for _ in range(1):
 test('100 and 100', [6000] * 100 + [18000] * 100 + [6000], 500, 'μs', 1e6)
test('1000 and 1000', [6000] * 1000 + [18000] * 1000 + [6000], 50, 'μs', 1e6)
test('10000 and 10000', [6000] * 10000 + [18000] * 10000 + [6000], 5, 'ms', 1e3)
```